NOT NULL constraint failed on PUT request in Django
I'm new to Django and I'm having trouble handling form-data and raw data in PUT requests. I need to update records of a Person model via a PUT request. The Person model has several fields including fname, sname, age, and gender, all of which are required.
I have a view to handle the PUT request, and I’m trying to handle both JSON and form-data formats in the request body.
However, when I send a PUT request via Postman, I encounter the following error:
`
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: api_person.fname`

To handle different request formats, I first attempt to parse the request body as JSON. If JSON parsing fails, I fall back to handling form-data. Here’s the relevant part of my view:
`
   elif request.method == 'PUT':
            try:
                # Handling JSON data
                data = json.loads(request.body)
                fname = data.get('fname')
                sname = data.get('sname')
                age = data.get('age')
                gender = data.get('gender')
            except json.JSONDecodeError:
                # Handling form-data
                fname = request.PUT.get('fname')
                sname = request.PUT.get('sname')
                age = request.PUT.get('age')
                gender = request.PUT.get('gender')
            
            person.fname = fname
            person.sname = sname
            person.age = age
            person.gender = gender
            person.save()
            

            person_dict = convert(person,pk)
            person_dict['id'] = person.pk
            return sendSuccessCode(data=[person_dict],message="Task get successful.",status=200)

I expected this approach to handle both request formats seamlessly and update the Person record correctly. However, I encountered a NOT NULL constraint failed: api_person.fname error, which indicates that the fname field is missing or empty.
Here is body of request

Despite adding print statements and validation checks, I couldn’t figure out why fname is still missing. Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Despite adding print statements and validation checks, I couldn’t figure out why fname is still missing That's odd.  Printing the data should have revealed the exact problem.  Please show us the print output.

Hmm -- you said this was a PUT request, however you're fetching the data from request.POST instead of request.PUT.  Maybe that's the problem?

@JohnGordon request.PUT doesn't exist in Django 5.x

Show us the contents of request.body.

@JohnGordon I replaced request.POST with request.PUT
giving following error
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'PUT'
Although i updated question with form-data Screenshot.

Yeah, @LordElrond pointed out that request.PUT doesn't exist.  My bad, I assumed it did.

Can you show us the contents of request.body and request.POST ?

@LordElrond Hey Lord do you any better way to handle both Form-data and raw data. can rest framework do that ?

@FenilTrivedi I can take a look at your question again tomorrow. In the meantime can  post the contents of request.POST and request.body?

If you want to use more HTTP methods than just GET or POST consider using Django REST framework.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I want to it from scratch
